# Homogeneous coordinates of a line in the projective plane

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

What are the homogeneous coordinates $\lambda, \mu$ of the line $r: x_0+x_1=0$ in the projective frame $[0,0,1], [1,-1,0], [1,-1,2]$ in the projective plane $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb R)$ with associated homogeneous coordinates $x_0, x_1, x_2$? 
Aren't they $\lambda =0, \mu =1$? (and why?)

EDIT:

The rest of the exercise is:

$r': x_0-x_2=0$ is another line in $\Bbb{P^2(R^)}$ and $\lambda',\mu'$ are its coordinates in the projective frame $[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[2,3,2]$ (fundamental and unity points). Let $P_0[1,0,0] \not\in r\cup r'$ and $f: r\rightarrow r'$ such that $f(P)=L(P,P_0)\cap r'$.

I have to write the expression of $f$ in the coordinates $[\lambda,\mu]$, $[\lambda',\mu']$ and see that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question? It looks like you are using $x_0$ and $x_1$ in two different ways.

Comment: I'm not, why are they different?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, you are saying $x_0=[0:0:1]$, $x_1=[1:-1:0]$, and $x_2=[1:-1:2]$ and then defining $r$ to be the line $x_0+x_1=0$ which does not make much sense.

Comment: No, those three points are the fundamental and unity points of the projective frame I'm considering and $x_0, x_1, x_2$ are the names of the coordinates. In the same projective plane I could have another projective frame with three different points but same "names" of the homogeneous coordinates

Comment: I see, my apologies. In that case, $x_0+x_1=0$ defines a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore corresponds to a line in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ instead of a single point. Was this intended?

Comment: Yes. ((How) do you think I should edit the question to make it clearer?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108866/discussion-between-anonymous-and-user735782).