# homogeneus coordinates and application between lines

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

So I was trying this exercise, but I have a lot of doubts:

$P^2\Bbb{(R)}$ projective plane and $x_0,x_1,x_2$ its homogeneous coordinates. Now consider two lines $r: x_0+x_1=0$ and $r': x_0-x_2=0$. Let $\lambda, \mu$ be the homogeneus coordinates of $r$ in the projective frame of $[0,0,1],[1,-1,0]$ and $[1,-1,2]$. Let $\lambda', \mu'$ be the homogeneus coordinates of $r'$ in the projective frame of $[0,1,0],[1,0,1]$ and $[2,3,2]$. Now take $P_0=[1,0,0]$ and $f: r\rightarrow r'$ such that for each $P\in r$, $f$ associate $P'=L(P_0 P)\cap r'$. (where $L(P_0 P)$ is the line from $P_0$ and $P$)

Show $f$ in the coordinates of $\lambda, \mu,\lambda', \mu'$.

Comment: I tried to post this exercise here as well and I didn't get any useful answers but (since I got some comments about this) I think you should specify that **you know** that those are only **two** fundamental points and unity point (do you know how they usually call them in english?) and they're not linearly independent.

Comment: I didn't see your question, anyway I didn't find an English way to describe these points (I think they just call them a projective frame or projective points).

Comment: "projective frame" is correct, but homogeneous coordinates of a line should be three $(\lambda, \mu, \nu)$ or do you mean that $\nu=1$ ?

Comment: @Arianna here is my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704697/735782. We might discuss this problem in chat if you want...

Comment: @JeanMarie would you mind clarifying how do we find these $(\lambda, \mu, \nu)$ you're referring to? Or maybe just point us in the right direction for some further research?

Comment: @Flutterblaxi In the same way a point has 3 coordinates, by duality a line has 3 homogeneous coordinates. You will need only two coordinates if you consider $L$ as a member of a **pencil of lines** : $L=\lambda L_1 + \mu L_2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie But since the problem says that $\lambda, \mu$ are the homogeneous coordinates of $r$ in some projective frame this shouldn't be the case, right? Or do you think interpreting $r$ as a member of a pencil of lines might lead to a solution?